# Integers writing as 0?

Tags: java

I'm working on a 2D RPG. I have started writing a save and load function but whenever I save my values return even though, I know (by printing using System.out.println) that the values are in fact NOT 0. Any help would be awesome!

```
private int lives;
private int health;
private int progress;
private int score;

private int[] saveInformation = { health, lives, progress, score };

public void save() {
    savePlayer("Resources/Save/playersave.txt");
}

public void savePlayer(String filePath) {
    File outputFile;
    BufferedWriter outputWriter;

    try {
        outputFile = new File(filePath);
        outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

        for (int i = 0; i < saveInformation.length; i++) {
            outputWriter.write(Integer.toString(saveInformation[i]) + "\n");
        }
        outputWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readPlayer(String filePath) {
    File inputFile;
    BufferedReader inputReader;

    try {
        inputFile = new File(filePath);
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        String fileText = inputReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(fileText);
        inputReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Without more information there isn't much we can do. Your array and loop are fine, and when I tested with static values (`int[] saveInformation = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`) it worked fine, printing the integers. You should add some debugging statements, and double check that the values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: I have checked the values and made sure they were what I was expecting, but whenever I try and run the save method they get written as 0.

Comment: The issue is with the values in your array, not your output code. I tested your exact method, and it wrote to a file as expected. Debug and output the values of each array index before you output to file. Add `System.out.println(Integer.toString(saveInformation[i]));` above the `outputWriter.write` line.

Answer (score 1):

You define your fields like this:

```
private int lives;
private int health;
private int progress;
private int score;

private int[] saveInformation = { health, lives, progress, score };
```

The type `int` is a *primitive* type. That array contains the current value of the four fields. Which, because the class is just being created, is zero. When you change those variables, the content of `saveInformation` is not going to change, as `int` is not a reference type.

Even if they were reference type, you'd have to modify the data inside the object for this to be reflected in the array. Assigning to a variable like `health` would not change the value that was already placed in `saveInformation`.

Note that you are also not doing anything in your reader. But first change the method that saves, so that it saves the variables themselves, not an array based on their initial value.